# Template parse errors - Angular 4 html template

Tags: angular

```
I want to display the hyperlinks to make it as generic single hyperlink with iteration. I have a string array in constants with key ,value,param property and want to read those and display them
```

other-account-information works!
    
    
      
        
        {{otheraccountinfolink.value}}

Getting parse error

```
Parser Error: **Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 15 in [onlinkselected({{param}})]** in ng:///AppModule/OtherAccountInformationComponent.html@6:87 ("p-6"></div>

        <a id="{{otheraccountinfolink.key}}_lnk_lbl" href="{{otheraccountinfolink.value}}" [ERROR ->](click)="onlinkselected({{param}})">{{otheraccountinfolink.value}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    "): ng:///AppModule/OtherAccountInformationComponent.html@6:87
    Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 17 in [onlinkselected({{param}})] in ng:///AppModule/OtherAccountInformationComponent.html@6:87 ("p-6"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the interpolation sign ({{}}).

```
 (click)="onlinkselected(param)"
```

Comment: If i remove (click)="onlinkselected({{otheraccountinfolink.param}})" error is gone. so issue is with the event.

Comment: It's not with the event, it's with the way you are using the {{}} because you are dealing with html so you should pass the otheraccountinfolink.param as it's with the function parameter like i mentioned on my answer.

Comment: Removed{{}} parse error is not there now. But VM122 vendor.bundle.js:78979 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for OtherAccountInformation! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for OtherAccountInformation!(…) Error: No provider for OtherAccountInformation! getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `{{}}` from all the attributes in html.

Interpolation should use when you are only printing the value on the screen when using in any attributes you can directly use variable names.

Comment: in my page i amhaving multiple links and those links i am iterating through the loop. <div *ngFor="let otheraccountinfolink of otheraccountinfolinks;  let i = index" id="{i}_div">
    <div id="{{otheraccountinfolink.key}}_id" class="p-6"></div>
    <a id="{{otheraccountinfolink.key}}_lnk_lbl" href="{{otheraccountinfolink.value}}" (click)="onlinkselected(otheraccountinfolink.param)">{{otheraccountinfolink.value}}</a>
  </div>...actually i want toreplace the value of otheraccountinfolink.param here in the html

Comment: You can directly use otheraccountinfolink.param = value. with what ever value you want on the UI.
Some example on how I am doing where I want a value to modify on the UI.
(click)="queryList = ''; filteredList = []"

Comment: Removed{{}} parse error is not there now. But VM122 vendor.bundle.js:78979 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for OtherAccountInformation! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for OtherAccountInformation!(…) Error: No provider for OtherAccountInformation! getting this error –

Comment: <div *ngFor="let otheraccountinfolink of otheraccountinfolinks;  let i = index" id="{i}_div">
        <div id="{{otheraccountinfolink.key}}_id" class="p-6"></div>
        <a id="{{otheraccountinfolink.key}}_lnk_lbl" href="{{otheraccountinfolink.value}}" (click)="onlinkselected(otheraccountinfolink.param)">{{otheraccountinfolink.value}}</a>
      </div>

Comment: try adding 

providers: [OtherAccountInformation]. 

or try adding it to following 

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    OtherAccountInformation<-- Add the module
]

Comment: This is how it is working for me 
<label>Local: {{localField}}</label> // for showing the plan values.
<input type="number" [formControlName]="'localWithholding' + (id + 1)". // for giving a name and adding one on each iteration as I will have multiple fields with same name.

Comment: Providers on my component.ts  file rigth?

Comment: yeah. Try adding there or else try importing it in module. As I don't know your complete code bit confused.